# In bash, how do a replace a string in a file with a dynamic replacement

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Specifically, I have a Markdown document with figures listed as so

````
```
![Figure XXX](images/figure-of-a-thing.png)
...
![Figure XXX](images/figure-of-another-thing.png)
```
````

I'd like to end up with the following:

````
```
![Figure 1](images/figure-of-a-thing.png)
...
![Figure 2](images/figure-of-another-thing.png)
```
````

I.e., with a monotonically increasing number. It strikes me that there are some sed/awk ninjas out there who can solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say

```
awk '/^!\[Figure/ { sub(/XXX/, ++n) } 1' filename.md
```

This will replace the first occurrence of `XXX` in all lines that begin with `![Figure` with a running counter.

If the `![Figure` sequences can also appear in the middle of a line and possibly several times in one line (I don't think this is probable, but for the sake of completeness, let's consider the case), you might use

```
awk 'BEGIN { n = 1 } { while(sub(/!\[Figure XXX/, "![Figure " n)) ++n; } 1' filename.md
```

Comment: Awesome. I had to make a small change, but on the money:
```
awk 'BEGIN {n=1} { if(sub(/XXX/, n)) {++n;} } 
```

Comment: Ah, okay. If there's no worry of false positives, that is simpler, of course. You could cut it down a bit further to `awk 'BEGIN { n = 1 } sub(/XXX/, n) { ++n } 1'`, if you wanted.